# Angular ng-repeat tag not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm toying with a simple angular example and I haven't figured out why my ng-repeat directive isn't working. The snippet below is just a controller reaching out to github to pull user and repo data back.

I can confirm that I'm getting both user and repo data back, that it's shaped the way I expect, and that the repos collection exists in $scope when onRepos() returns. I just can't seem to get the repo names to render using ng-repeat. I don't see any errors in the console, it just doesn't want to work.

I've spent the last 30 minutes staring at this and can't figure it out. What have I missed?

angular 1.3.15

app.js

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('githubviewer',[]);

  var MainController = function($scope, $http) {

    var onUserComplete = function(response) {
      $scope.user = response.data;
      $http.get($scope.user.repos_url)
        .then(onRepos, onError);
    }

    var onRepos = function(response) {
      $scope.repos = response.data;
      console.log($scope.repos[0].name);
    }

    var onError = function(response) {
      $scope.error = response.data;
    }

    $scope.search = function(username) {
      var url = "https://api.github.com/users/" + username;
      $http.get(url).then(onUserComplete, onError);
    }

    $scope.message = "github viewer";
    $scope.usename = "angular";
  }

  app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http", MainController ]);
}());
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="githubviewer">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Angular JS - Getting Started</title>
  <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div> {{message}} </div>
    <div> {{error}} </div>
     <form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search(username)">
      <input type="search" required placeholder="Username to find" ng-model="username">
      <input type="submit" value="search">
    </form>  
    <div>
      <h2> Name : {{user.name}} </h2>
      <img ng-src="{{user.avatar_url}}" title="{{user.name}}">
    </div>
  </div>

  Repos: {{repos.length}} 
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos">
        <td>{{ repo.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `table` tag outside of `MainController` scope. Move it inside div containing `ng-controller` attribute.

Comment: And there it is. I don't know why that didn't occur to me.